# how can i know is there a bug in my table?

Tags: database, laravel

Following is the table structure in Laravel and it seems there is a bug in it. Can anyone guide me?
This bug is making some problems for the future for my project.

I cant find anything suspicious myself

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserBaseInfosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user__base__infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_Name');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('family');
            $table->text('password');
            $table->boolean('block');
            $table->integer('num_reported');
            $table->boolean('is_sms_send');
            $table->boolean('is_email_send');
            $table->integer('link_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('link_id')->references('id')->on('links');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user__base__infos');
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think there is a bug?

Comment: By looking everything's fine, can you be specified what exactly is the bug you're getting

Comment: please show us the error which you are facing? we can't assume the bug.

Comment: I suggest you add some `indexes` in order of future performance based on your searches criteria. That is what we can suggest, nothing else seems bad with the table's design. [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: by bug i mean in the future maybe database has some problems or isnt it right from  logical thinking

Comment: Corrected grammar

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

from:

```
$table->text('password');
```

to:

```
$table->string('password');
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think that this solves the problem?